# How to remove store from ydn.db?

Tags: ydn-db

I am using ydn.db from local storage. 
Which function can be used to remove the store using YDB.DB library ? 
The stores i have added is as follows

```
var schema = {
  stores: [{
      name:'consignments',
    keyPath:"timeStamp"
    }];

var db = new ydn.db.Storage('localhost', schema);
```

I wish to check whether the store exist in localstorage and if it exists delete the store and if not exist add the store.

Answer (score 0):

If store exist or not can be known only after opening the database. If a schema does not a store name, but exit in the connected database, the existing store will be removed.

To delete the database

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('localhost', schema);
```

To delete above the database,

```
ydn.db.deleteDatabase(db.getName(), db.getType());
```

If type of database is not known

```
ydn.db.deleteDatabase('localhost');
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the `deleteDatabase` function like this:

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase(storage_name);
```

see the doc here: https://dev.yathit.com/api/ydn/db/index.html